is there a way to add 3d text effect in flutter?
I am new to learning Flutter and I am really inspired by the "!Not Boring Calculator" app (if you haven't checked out the app, please do - it's really good). In this app, there is a 3D number effect which I am trying to recreate. I know there's a lot going on behind the scenes, but I want to create a similar-ish type of effect. Do you have any suggestions on how I can do that?
!not boring calculator screenshot
thanks in advance.
i have tired this package of threeDtextpainter but its not giving any good result
here's code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ThreeDText extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final double fontSize;
  final Color color;
  final double depth;

  ThreeDText({
    required this.text,
    this.fontSize = 40,
    this.color = Colors.black,
    this.depth = 4,
  });


Try below code for 3D effect on text without any package.
        Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              top: 1,
              left: 4,
              child: Transform(
                transform: Matrix4.identity()
                  ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.002) // Perspective
                  ..rotateX(0.25), // Adjust for 3D effect
                child: Text(
                  '0',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 170,
                    color: Colors.grey[600],
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              child: Text(
                '0',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 150,
                  color: Colors.grey[500],
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),

